# Problem in define Orientation Property For My UerControl in WPF?

Tags: wpf

i have textbox and progressbar in my usercontrol that place in stackpanel.
i write a Orientation Property but it doesnt work???
if orientation set to horizontal,textbox and progressbar should be place horizontally and if orientation set to vertically,textbox and progressbar should be place Vertically.
my code is :

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBox Name="TValue" Width="40" Height="23" TextChanged="TValue_TextChanged"/>
        <ProgressBar Name="PG1" Width="200" Height="23"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and my property is:

```
//Define Orientation Property

        public Orientation Orientation
        {
            get { return (Orientation)GetValue(OrientationProperty); }
            set { SetValue(OrientationProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Orientation.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty OrientationProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Orientation", typeof(Orientation), typeof(TPUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(Orientation.Horizontal));
```

if u can help me,u save me from storm,THNX

Comment: What you want to do? changing oriention of the stackpanel?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you have:

1. Created a UserControl (lets call it MyUserControl).
2. Created a dependency property Orientation for MyUserControl.
3. Within usercontrol you have a stackpanel and you want to bind the Orientation of this stackpanel with Orientation property of MyUserControl.

Try this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="{Binding Orientation, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                 AncestorType={x:Type MyUserControl }}}">
         <TextBox Name="TValue" Width="40" Height="23" TextChanged="TValue_TextChanged"/>
         <ProgressBar Name="PG1" Width="200" Height="23"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Suggestions:

1. Be more explicit while asking for help. You stated a problem (and that
   too not clearly) and then didn't even mention the question. :)
2. You may want to check if defining a ControlTemplate helps in your scenario.